# Load data into Cassandra denormalized table

Tags: cassandra, denormalization

I understand that as Cassandra does not support join, we need to create denormalized table sometimes.
Given I need to get Item names for each item within a order given order Id, I create a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  order_id int,
  item_id int,
  item_name,
  primary key ((id), item_id)
);
```

I have two csv files to load data from, order.csv and item.csv, where order.csv contains order_id and item_id and item.csv contains item_id and item_name.

The question is how to load data from the csv file into the table I create? I insert data from order file first and it works fine. When I do a insertion of item, it will throw error saying missing primary key.

Any idea how I can insert data from different input files into the denormalized table? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At last I wrote some code to merge the two csv files before importing into the database.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo on the definition of the primary key, it should be

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  order_id int,
  item_id int,
  item_name,
  primary key (order_id, item_id)
);
```

Are you using [COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) to upload the data?

Regarding the denormalization, that depends on your use case, usually on a normalized schema you will have one table for orders, another for customers and do a join with SQL to display information of the order and customers at the same time; in this case, for a denormalized table you will have the order and the customer information in the same table, the fields will depend on how you are going to use the query.

As a rule of thumb, before creating the table, you first need to define what that are you going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Using a secondary index on your `item_id` should do the trick:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_item_id ON order (item_id);
```

Now you should be able to query like:

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE item_id = ?;
```

Beware that indexes usually have performance impacts, so you can use them to import your data, and drop them when finished.

Please refer to the [Cassandra Index Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/usePrimaryIndex.html) for further information.